# StarCraft Map Dimensions

Tags: logic

In StarCraft Brood War, a map's maximum dimension in either the X or Y direction is 256 cells. A map's dimension is required to be a multiple of 32. Each cell is 32 pixels in both directions (And probably some path finding limitations) and I assume this is the reason for the previous requirement. Thus 256*32=8,192. But when we're talking about the addresses of the game, where does this number come from? What bit size is this number being stored in? 4? 8? 16? (Or, alternatively, is it being stored in multiple addresses being "patched together" so to speak, like in other games?)

From my own (limited) experience with looking at the RAM of games in emulators or through something like Cheat Engine, I'm accustomed to an address being either 4 or 8 hex numbers long (Such as 015F or 015FFA2B)

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is an "address of the game"? What dod you mean by "Where does this number come from?"? The bit size is whatever the programmers chose it to be and, unless the developers are here to tell us, nobody else will know. Fundamentally, though, how is this computer science?

Comment: It seems that $256=2^8$, so perhaps the X,Y coordinates are stored as bytes (though it's impossible to know). The number 32 might come from completely different considerations, such as graphics. I'm not sure that 8192 has any particular significance other than being the product of 256 and 32.